# Android spinnerStyle not working

Tags: java, android, android-holo-everywhere

First excuse me for my english.

Im designing a theme (With HoloEveryWhere) and im trying to style default spinner.

The problem is that the **spinnerStyle is not working**. I'm testing with this layout.

```
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spCountry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/etPhone" />
```

And im using this for my theme.xml..

```
 <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Coloquium.Spinner.Ruby</item>
```

and in styles.xml

```
<style name="Coloquium.Spinner.Ruby" parent="@style/Holo.Spinner.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_holo_white</item>
</style>
```

The problem is that the spinner style is never applied **(Others styles like edittextstyle or buttonstyle works fine)**, the background never change, But i tried this style as spinnerItemStyle and work fine, but spinnerItemStyle is the inner view, and i want to style the outer, the spinner.

**If i set background directly in the layout node, the background change fine**, but i need to set spinnerStyle for all spinners in the theme, not in layout.

I test a lot of post looking for a solution without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

HoloEveryWhere appear use "spinnerStyle" and not "android:spinnerStyle".

But really... I can't find the HoloEveryWhere documentation about this. :S